# Is 'event' a reserved word in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, events, reserved-words

I am a beginner to Javascript. And when I was practicing I have noticed something.

Take this function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showChar(sSomeData, oEvent)
    {
        alert (oEvent.keyCode);
        return true;
    }

</script>
```

When I call this function as this:

```
 <input type="text" id="txtTextBox" onkeypress="return showChar('some text', oEvent);" />
```

I get a JS error: "Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'oEvent' is undefined"

But if I rename oEvent with 'event' like:

```
<input type="text" id="txtTextBox" onkeypress="return showChar('some text', event);" />
```

Then it works fine. My conclusion is 'event'is a reserved word which stands for event 
argument in Java Script. But when I have checked the net I did not see 'event' as a reserved word.

Am I mistaken or it is not really documented as a reserved word?

Thanks!

Comment: if you add tags for javascript, use 'javascript' and not 'java' and 'script'

Comment: Seconded. I died a little inside.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It is not a reserved keyword, but it is a global variable in IE at least.

Comment: Then for other browser what should I use as a variable name that can stand for event argument in this case?

Comment: Your problem is not the name, it the way event attributes work. See Ionut's answer below (Which should be voted up).

Comment: That `event` variable it's actually an argument which is shadowing the global `event` variable in IE. That's why it work in **both** IE and FF.

Answer (score 36):

What initially made this confusing for me is not understanding how the *conventions* for coding event handlers actually worked versus what was a *named variable*, combined with the implicit calls done by Javascript handlers when you set up event handlers like this:

*Good 1*

```
document.getElementById('testId').onkeypress = function(e) {
     console.log(e.which);
}
```

Above, your browser is passing `event` to the handler as the function's first argument implicitly, so you can name your parameter (here, `e`) **anything you want as long as you're consistent**, even if you go crazy like this:

*Good 2; creatively named*

```
document.getElementById('testId').onkeypress = function(aWhopBopALuWhop) {
     console.log(aWhopBopALuWhop.which);
}
```

**But because of the way `event` is used as a global**, cruddy code like this also works:

*Cruddy scoping 1*

```
document.getElementById('testId').onkeypress = function(aWhopBopALuWhop) {
     console.log(event.which);   // <<< decidedly NOT aWhopBopALuWhop
}
```

So you might also see doubly cruddy code like this:

*Cruddy Scoping 2*

```
document.getElementById('testId').onkeypress = function(event) {
     console.log(event.which);
}
```

Now which `event` is `event`?  Unfortunately, it doesn't matter.  Regardless of scoping, we put `event` into `event` so `event` === `event` throughout! [sic]

But this does demonstrate that `event` *isn't* a reserved word.  It's a variable.  So where you can't say `break = "spam";`, you *can* say `event = "spam";`.  So if you try to use `break`, which *is* reserved, it borks.

```
document.getElementById('testId').onkeypress = function(break) {
     console.log(break.which);
}
```

What's important to learn (and what [Ionut is essentially saying, I believe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1510142/1028230)), is that **your browser** is silently passing the "global" `event` var into your `onkeypress` handler no matter what you call it in your function definition.  Confusingly, even if you don't use your parameter to access `event` within your handler, you can still access `event` as a global, as show in *Cruddy 1 & 2*, above.

Now when I was calling from html-land with an `onkeypress`, paradigms started mixing in my head.  Here, there is no silent passing of `event` into your handler function's arguments.  You have to explicitly pass `event` yourself, like so:

```
<script>
    function handlerNamed(namedParam) {
        console.log(namedParam.which);
    }
</script>
<input type="text" size="10" onkeypress="handlerNamed(event)"><br />
```

**No other convention works!**  And this only works because the browsers support it, not because any ECMAscript standard defines `event` (afaik).  You **cannot** use any of the below like you "could" with .onKeyPress by changing the name of the parameter to match in `handlerNamed`:

```
<!-- NONE OF THESE WORK, b/c ONLY event is defined! -->
<input type="text" size="10" onkeypress="handlerNamed(evt)"><br />
<input type="text" size="10" onkeypress="handlerNamed(e)"><br />
<input type="text" size="10" onkeypress="handlerNamed(aWhopBopALuWhop)"><br />
```

Make sense?  I was in the middle of [a much too complicated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rufwork/yHw4S/) trying to write this up before it finally clicked in case that's helpful.

Comment: `event` passed as a function argument used to throw in Firefox, and `e` is commonly used to represent error objects, which is why I always use `evt` and never use `event` at all to avoid any confusion.

Answer (score 10):

Well, the code:

```
onkeypress="return showChar('some text', oEvent);"
```

Is the equivalent of the following JavaScript code:

```
element.onkeypress = function (eventObjectName) {
    return showChar('some text', eventObjectName);
};
```

It's just that browsers name the event argument as `event`.

So, the value of the attribute is wrapped in a JS function which receives an argument named `event` which is the event object.

Comment: The equivalent would be `element.onkeypress = function (e) { return showChar('some text', oEvent); };` or (for IE) `element.onkeypress = function () { return showChar('some text', oEvent); };`

Comment: @outis, but `oEvent` would be `undefined` in your example.

Answer (score 8):

No, `event` is not a reserved word. It is, however, a variable which is set by all the major browsers when an event handler (such as onkeypress) of a DOM node is being executed. In IE, it is also a global variable.

A typical cross-browser way to get the event is along these lines.

On the DOM node:

```
<div onclick='someFunction(event)'>Click me</div>
```

The event handling function:

```
function someFunction(evt) {
  var srcElem = evt.srcElement || evt.target;

  // Code continues
}
```

By the way, in your example, `oEvent` is the name of the parameter and is therefore valid in the context of the function being called, not in the context of the caller.

Comment: Does event has to be the always the first parameter in function?

Comment: The event object will be the first parameter that the browser sends to your handler. However, once you have it, you can do whatever you like with it.

In the example I gave, you could ignore event with:
onclick='someFunction()'

Or you could pass it as a parameter other than the first:
onclick='someFunction(123, event)'

Answer (score 5):

[List of javascript reserved words](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/JavaScript/Reserved_Words)

Comment: The linked to document does not contain 'event', so I think it would be useful to say "event is not a reserved word", rather than just posting the URL.

Answer (score 2):

This is old, but since I stumbled over it I figure I might as well answer.

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_reserved.asp says that event is NOT a reserved word, as mentioned in the comments above. However, if you read further down the page....

"Windows Reserved Words
JavaScript can be used outside HTML. It can be used as the programming language in many other applications.

In HTML you must (for portability you should) avoid using the name of HTML and Windows objects and properties:"

And 'event' is displayed in the table below. So can you use it? Sure. Should you use it? No. There are heaps of examples on stackoverflow that use event, but they're using it for clarity. When you use that code, you need to edit it.