# Prevent Default is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, preventdefault

I have checked around here and none of these solution on here fix my issue. 
I cannot seem to get the preventDefault() to work. Code below:

Jquery:

```
$("#changepassword").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // stop normal form submission
    $.ajax({
        url: "changePassword.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: $(this).serialize(), // you also need to send the form data
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(html) {
            $("#s-window").append(html);
        }
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
    <div id="s-window">
        <form id="changepassword" action="changePassword.php" method="POST">
            <input type="password" name="currentPassword" placeholder="Current Password"/>
            <input type="password" name="newPassword" placeholder="New Password"/>
            <input type="password" name="confirmPassword" placeholder="Confirm Password"/>
            <input class="button" type="submit" value="Change Password" />
        </form>
    </div>
```

There are no errors on my conosle. The changePassword.php works as it is supposed to. But rather than updating my #s-window it redirects me to the changePassword.php page

How can I recode this to make everything happen on the page?

Comment: Why not remove the `form` attributes if you are using ajax anyway.

Comment: Mostly because I have no idea what I am doing. I can do that if it will work? Do you have anything that can explain why I would make those changes?

Comment: Look, your code anyways calls the same php method through ajax. So the form `action` attribute is of no use. Try removing the `action` and `method` from form tag.

Comment: Removing those tags caused it to not send me to a new page, but it still refreshed the entire page. I was hoping to only update that s-window.

Comment: Hopefully silly question: is the jQuery library loaded before your code?

Comment: Pretty sure it is. Its loaded in the header, and the header loads on all pages. 
Although... Would it need to be loaded on the changePassword.php script? I didnt think that would matter... 
Also, is it a problem to have two different libs loaded?

Comment: [Your code](http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/doa6qLar/) runs correctly, so there must be another problem. Perhaps there's still a JS error somewhere else, which you're not seeing because the URL changes right away.

Comment: Why you are using dataType: "html". just change it to dataType: "script it will work".I have updated my answer below.

Comment: I just looked in your fiddle. I dont see how you know the code works properly. It sits there and does nothing? Doesnt clear the forms or anything that I can see that would indicate it worked?

Comment: Did you wait until document ready before initializing it with the jquery submit?

Comment: No I dont. Can you show me what you mean? And explain what that would do?

Comment: Take a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/qpx77jj0/

Comment: If you run your code to bind the form with the submit event before the dom is loaded, the code will do nothing.

Comment: @Hoyen Hoyen: You seemed to have nailed it. Its not perfect yet. but it changes the password while leaving me on the same page. If you would like to submit it as an answer I can select it?

Comment: Ok, I just added a answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wait until document is ready:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#changepassword").submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault(); // stop normal form submission
        $.ajax({
            url: "changePassword2.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: $(this).serialize(), // you also need to send the form data
            dataType: "html",
            success: function(html) {
                $("#s-window").append(html);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way using `return false;`, if you have any confusion see here more [event.preventDefault() vs. return false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false)

```
$("#changepassword").submit(function(event) {
  //event.preventDefault(); // stop normal form submission
   return false;
});
```

Comment: This still redirected me to the changePassword.php script. Which is just a blank white page.

Answer (score 0):

In you ajax call change `dataType: "html"` to `dataType: "script"`

Comment: It makes no difference. The two are equivalent.

Comment: it's different he is using submit function while i am asking to use it with 'on'

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/submit says: "This method is a shortcut for `.on( "submit", handler )`"

Comment: I tried your solution as well. It redirected me to my php script page.

Answer (score 0):

At least in IE, `event` is a global variable (as per [Is 'event' a reserved word in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510094/is-event-a-reserved-word-in-javascript)). This may not be the cause of your problem, but it might be a good idea to change your naming nonetheless.

Comment: I can change event to e or something else if you tihnk that might be the problem?

Comment: Give it a shot. If nothing else, it would be a bit tidier. `e` would be a fine name.